# How do I get the correct view size for UIModalPresentationFormSheet in iOS 8?

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios8, autolayout

I've got a view that I show with a UIModalPresentationFormSheet presentation style on the iPad for a welcome screen. Here is the code to present the view. This is called in viewDidLoad for my main screen if the welcome screen has not been shown before.

```
UIStoryboard *welcomeStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Welcome_%@", (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad ? @"iPad" : @"iPhone")] bundle:nil];
    self.welcomeViewController = [welcomeStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"welcome"];

if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad){
    self.welcomeViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;

    if(IS_OS_8_OR_LATER){
        self.welcomeViewController.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(540.0f, 620.0f);
    }
}

[self presentViewController:self.welcomeViewController animated:NO completion:NULL];
```

On iOS 7 the view is sized properly and the content flows as it should:

[image: Form Sheet on iOS 7]

On iOS 8 the modal size is correct, but the view still thinks it is full screen. When I write the view size to the log it is 768 x 1024 after viewDidAppear (where it is 540 x 620 on iOS 7)

[image: Form Sheet on iOS 8]

How do I tell the modal view to be the same size as the form sheet?